# Is there a way to let sqlformat or another SQL formatter change only a selection within a file in VIM?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, formatting

I added a shortcut in VIM so that I can press `Esc` and `,pt` to get the automatic sql formatting from sqlformat command.

Taken from [Can VIM autoindent SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577367/can-vim-autoindent-sql).

```
"autocmd FileType sql call SqlFormatter()
nnoremap call SqlFormatter()
augroup end
function SqlFormatter()
    set noai
    " set mappings...
    map ,pt  :%!sqlformat --reindent --indent_width 4 --keywords upper --identifiers lower -<CR>
endfunction
```

I commented out `autocmd FileType sql call SqlFormatter()` and replaced it with `nnoremap call SqlFormatter()` to have it available in any file since often, I have SQL code that is embedded in another language and I thought I might perhaps use it only on a selection of the file.

What I need: In visual mode of vim (`Esc`+`v`), I want to mark something, and then press a shortcut of my choice to reformat ***only the marked code***.

1. Is there away to make vim treat the selection as its own file perhaps, like its own buffer, so that sqlformat?
2. Another way would be to change sqlformat: add a parameter that allows applying it only to a selection. Such a parameter is not yet there:

```bash
usage: sqlformat  [OPTIONS] FILE, ...

Format FILE according to OPTIONS. Use "-" as FILE to read from stdin.

positional arguments:
  filename

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o FILE, --outfile FILE
                        write output to FILE (defaults to stdout)
  --version             show program's version number and exit

Formatting Options:
  -k CHOICE, --keywords CHOICE
                        change case of keywords, CHOICE is one of "upper", "lower", "capitalize"
  -i CHOICE, --identifiers CHOICE
                        change case of identifiers, CHOICE is one of "upper", "lower", "capitalize"
  -l LANG, --language LANG
                        output a snippet in programming language LANG, choices are "python", "php"
  --strip-comments      remove comments
  -r, --reindent        reindent statements
  --indent_width INDENT_WIDTH
                        indentation width (defaults to 2 spaces)
  -a, --reindent_aligned
                        reindent statements to aligned format
  -s, --use_space_around_operators
                        place spaces around mathematical operators
  --wrap_after WRAP_AFTER
                        Column after which lists should be wrapped
  --comma_first COMMA_FIRST
                        Insert linebreak before comma (default False)
  --encoding ENCODING   Specify the input encoding (default utf-8)
```

3. Would it perhaps work with plugins/wrappers like the vim plugin "vim-autoformat" and/or "sqlparse" within VIM? (see the link above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `:h 'formatprg'` you can use to format a portion of the text with `gq`.

For your case this might work (added to `.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim`):

```
setlocal formatprg=sqlformat\ --reindent\ --indent_width\ 4\ --keywords\ upper\ --identifiers\ lower\ -
```

NOTE: I didn't test it as I use `sql-formatter` implemented in node:

```
" npm i -g sql-formatter
if executable('sql-formatter')
    setlocal formatprg=sql-formatter\ -i\ 4\ --lines-between-queries\ 3
    command -buffer Fmt :%!sql-formatter -i 4 --lines-between-queries 3
endif
```

Once you have it set up you can visually select a query and press `gq`. Or as usual, format all buffer with `gggqG`, or a paragraph with `gqap` etc.

PS, instead of `.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim` you can use autocommand with filetype event and set `formatprg` there.

[image]

Comment: I do not know whether I have tested it correctly. Using `autocmd FileType sql call setlocal formatprg=sqlformat\ --reindent\ --indent_width\ 4\ --keywords\ upper\ --identifiers\ lower\ -` throws `Error detected while processing FileType Autocommands for "sql":
E107: Missing parentheses: setlocal formatprg=sqlformat\ --reindent\ --indent_width\ 4\ --keywords\ upper\ --identifiers\ lower\ -
Press ENTER or type command to continue`.

Comment: And pasting the same command `setlocal ...` in my `~/.vim/ftplugin/sql.vim` does not throw an error, but I do not know how to start it. `:h 'formatprg'` opens an "options.txt" window at the bottom of the screen. `gq`: `E492: Not an editor command: gq`

Comment: @questionto42 `~/.vim/ftplugin/sql.vim` should be `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim`. As for `:h 'formatprg'` -- it is a helptopic describing what `formatprg` option is.

Comment: @questionto42 `gq` is a normal mode command, thus, you should press `gq` in normal mode (or visual), NOT try to run it as `:gq`

Comment: @questionto42 as for `autocmd` -- why did you put `call` there? It doesn't belong there.

Comment: I was asked to check it in vscode / codium where I can also use your node.js "sql-formatter". I still want to have a formatter in VIM as well, I will try and change the code as you said, but lower prio now. I will let you know.